# Mocking stored procedure's output parameter

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have following method

```
public bool IsUserAllowedToDoThings(string userName, string thingToDo)
    {
        var outputParameter = new ObjectParameter("IsAllowed", typeof(bool?));
        _context.SP_IsUserAllowedToDoThings(userName, thingToDo, outputParameter);
        return (bool)outputParameter.Value;
    }
```

The method just calls SP using EF and return SP's output result. But I'm having problems to mock SP's output for unit testing. 
P.S. I'm using MOQ framework for mocking.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: I just don't know how to to setup mocked output parameter.

Comment: I was suggesting you add more info to the question, but if you think it's perfect just the way it is leave it that way ;) I won't be able to help I don't know C# or Moq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the MOQ's manual 3rd time I finally was able to find the way to do this. That was surprisingly simple:

```
 mockObjectContext.Setup(m => m.SP_IsUserAllowedToDoThings(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<ObjectParameter>())).Callback<string, string, ObjectParameter>((a, b, c) =>
        {
            c.Value = true;
        });
```